# Microsoft tools that can do some of the same work as Selenium and/or SOAPUI

Tags: selenium, tfs, soapui

I'm trying to get an idea of what Microsoft tools are available that can do some or all of the same testing as Selenium and soapUI.  I'm not looking for comments about which people prefer but rather what MS tools I can use that will integrate well with TFS.

Does anyone have any input?

Answer (score 0):

There's Microsoft Test Manager which can do a lot of what Selenium can do , but also integrates really well into your CI builds in TFS, I also believe it has a number of m good features for providing richer bug tracking and recording

Comment: Mike, thanks for your reply!  Do you have any reference links regarding the Selenium-like features in Test Manager? Regards, MikeA